# How get a single value from dataset LINQ without throwing Invalid cast exception with c#

Tags: c#, linq, exception, dataset, .net

i want get a single Int value from a data set, but i get stuck here, i dont know how convert int= "list int" with LINQ, that i believe is the reason for the exception that throws me in  "select d.Field("UserId");".

```
var Userid =
        from d in con.obtenerLasColumnasPorIdentificadorDeTabla("userprofile", "UserName", TXTnamePaso1.Text, "string").Tables["Tabla"].AsEnumerable()
        where d.Field<string>("UserName") == TXTnamePaso1.Text
        select d.Field<int>("UserId");
```

UPDATE 1: 
what i want is get a "UserId" value that is int primary key autoincrement from this [table](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/5230/qr4x.png) after getting the specific row through "UserName" string field

UPDATE 2: the method "obtenerLasColumnasPorIdentificadorDeTabla()" only modified the Sqlite consult, and return the table in DataSet format type.

```
public System.Data.DataSet obtenerLasColumnasPorIdentificadorDeTabla(string nombreTabla, string nombreColumnaParaIdentificar, T valorDeDatoAIdentificar, string tipoDatoValorIdentificar)
{
    string comillaIndexDinamica = "";

    if (tipoDatoValorIdentificar == "string")
            comillaIndexDinamica = "'"; 

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = ConeccionBaseDatosDirecta.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM " + nombreTabla + " WHERE "+nombreColumnaParaIdentificar+"="+comillaIndexDinamica+valorDeDatoAIdentificar+comillaIndexDinamica+";");
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `UserID`, invalid cast exception would only occur if it is not `int`, try `long`

Comment: Is UserId coming back as NULL? Have you tried changing the select to  select d.Field<int?>("UserId");

Comment: Note that the data type specified in the generic parameter T of the Field method and the SetField method must match the type of the underlying value. Otherwise, an InvalidCastException exception will be thrown. The specified column name must also match the name of a column in the DataSet, or an ArgumentException will be thrown. In both cases, the exception is thrown at run time during the enumeration of the data when the query is executed.

refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386916(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: no is int, i tried with .Single() and .SingleorDefault() and in both cases throw InvalidCastException, but now how can i get the value, because i can retrieve the table.

Comment: your Database Engine type is by any chance tinyint or smallint?

Comment: ok i will try with small an tiny int , My database is SqLite.

Comment: i tried with: char, sbyte, byte, int, int16, int32, int64, intPr Uint32, uint64, and always cast exception :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things seems to be happening - I would need to see the entire obtenerLasColumnasPorIdentificadorDeTabla() function to be certain.

1. You are passing "string" as the fourth parameter into obtenerLasColumnasPorIdentificadorDeTabla(), does this perhaps convert the output to string? If so, .NET cannot implicitly cast sting to INT, you would have to use a convert statement like so:

   int userId = Convert.ToInt32("123456");
2. obtenerLasColumnasPorIdentificadorDeTabla() only returns part of [UserProfile] table, possibly due to input parameters, and is not returning [UserID].

Comment: how UserId is INTEGER primary key in the sqlite table, maybe visual studio can not identify the data type INTEGER? Could be?

Comment: The problem certainly lies in converting a string representation of an integer to an actual integer which cannot be done implicitly in CSharp. You must *explicitly* convert it using a command... can you try this line: `select Convert.ToInt32(d.Field<string>("UserId"));` and see if it works?